# How can i line break when exporting to excel Datatable?

Tags: jquery, excel, datatable

In the code example below the numbers appear one after the other with the `br` tag, but it looks side by side in the Excel extension. How can I solve this?

```html
<div id="mytable">
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Numbers</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytable table').DataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    bLengthChange: false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [ 'excel' ],
    order: []
  });
});
```

Comment: Put the number in separate `td` elements in different rows. That's how the CSV is generated; by creating a 2d array from the table cells.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want this. Is there any way I can do this in the same <td> tag?

Comment: Not without creating your own Excel exporter, no